# Is there a shortcut for calling one-parameter XSL functions?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-1.0

I have many functions that takes in one input, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template name="F">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    ... ...
</xsl:template>
```

To call the function, I need to write:

```
<xsl:call-template name="F">
    <xsl:with-param name="input" select="'jkljkljkl'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

This seems overly verbose. Since the function has only one parameter, why do we have to write the `xsl:with-param` node?

Is there a shortcut for calling one-parameter functions?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="F" select-param="'jkljkl'"/>
```

It's short and sweet and equally non-ambiguous (since there's only one parameter). How can we call one-parameter functions in a short and sweet way?

<sub>Am looking for a solution in both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you can write **your own functions** by:

- **declaring your namespace**
- **defining the function** as a child of the transform root element, using [`xsl:function`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-function) declaration.

Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:nTan="http://nTan.comr">

  <xsl:function name="nTan:Hello">
   <xsl:param name="string1"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Hello ',$string1)"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="nTan:Hello('World!')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you, this is powerful information. however i do need a XSLT 1.0 solution too (i'm working on a project that does not have 2.0 transformer). for that, is there a solution?

Comment: No. XSLT 1.0 is highly verbose, and if you're going to use it, you have to live with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, however, it's worth noting that when you call a named template, the context node does not change. Depending on the context, you may be able to have the named template access what you'd be passing in as a parameter directly.

It's also possible to have a parameter that sets the current context node as the default value, so that you can call it without a parameter to refer to the current node, or optionally pass in a node.

For example with the input:

```
<foo>
  <input>xxx</input>
</foo>
```

Instead of this:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <xsl:call-template name="bar">
    <xsl:with-param name="myparam" select="input" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="bar">
  <xsl:param name="myparam" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('Value:',$myparam)" />
</xsl:template>
```

You can just do

```
<xsl:template match="input">
  <xsl:call-template name="bar" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="bar">
  <xsl:param name="myparam" select="." />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('Value:',$myparam)" />
</xsl:template>
```

In both cases, `$myparam` will be the `input` node. The `foo` template in the first example is also perfectly valid with the `bar` named template in the second; when you pass in a value to a parameter, it overrides the default specified on the `select` attribute of the templates `<xsl:param>` node.

Comment: I don't think this method will be able to address input parameters different from a node-set.

Comment: Of course not, but it can be passed in if required; this is only really a shortcut where the parameter being passed in is (or can be) derived from the context node. It's only a viable solution in some circumstances, but I don't believe there is a way of doing exactly what the OP asks.

Comment: is there a way to apply templates with something that is not a node? Like i want to apply-template to an arbitrary string 'xxx' (this value is not in a node, neither is it related to any node, but rather it is derived as the result of a series of calculations)

Comment: Unfortunately not, the `select` clause of the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction must be a node set; it's technically possible to construct one, but that's going to end up more complex than simply using `xsl:with-param` in the first place.